# How to change bootstrap collapse size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented bootstrap collapse panel in my code for registration form.Here is the image. Please tell me do I change the width and height so that I can bring it to center. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch this CSS

```
accordion-group {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
}

 //OR 
 //inline manner

 <div class="accordion-group" style="width: 50%;margin-left: 25%;" >
  ........
```

Make sure you put it after the Bootstrap CSS .
If it is not working then apply it inline in style attribute to **Div** having class **accordion-group**.

Comment: Thank you,but this is not working,maybe I did it wrong.`<div class="accordion-group">` I added this above the collapse panel div tag

Comment: yes `<style type="text/css">
        accordion-group {
      width: 50%;
      margin-left: 25%;
    }
    </style>`